# nested list using loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have following python code:

```
def display_game(guesses, clues):

    total = 'Guess\tClues\n****************\n'
    new = ''
    for i in range(len(guesses)):
        for letter in guesses[i]:
           new +=letter+ ' '
        return print(total+new +'\t'+ clue(clues)+'\n')      

def clue(clues):

    test = ''
    for i in range(len(clues)):
         for w in clues[i]:
            test = test + w + ' '
         return test.rstrip()
```

The output is suppose to look like:

```
>>> display_game([['Y', 'P', 'G', 'G'], ['O', 'O', 'G', 'G']], [['b', 'b'], ['b','b', 'b', 'b']])

Guess   Clues
****************
Y P G G b b
O O G G b b b b
```

I am getting this:

```
>>> display_game([['Y', 'P', 'G', 'G'], ['O', 'O', 'G', 'G']], [['b', 'b'], ['b','b', 'b', 'b']])

Guess   Clues
****************
Y P G G     b b
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: It is unclear what output you're expecting

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you want is understood to me (which is not a given), first of all, you don't need the range function to loop through lists; just use the `in` keyword.

Secondly, you are returning at the end of the first loop. Deindent your "return ...." statement and it should be OK.

Oh also, `return print(...)` makes no sense. You either print or you return.

Comment: i need the second sublist on the next line though for example display_game([['Y', 'P', 'G', 'G'], ['O', 'O', 'G', 'G']], [['b', 'b'], ['b','b', 'b', 'b']]) Y P G G would be on the first line and O O G G would be on the next line.

Comment: That's what the `\n` accomplishes in your `print()` statement.

Comment: but when i run my code the list [['Y', 'P', 'G', 'G'], ['O', 'O', 'G', 'G']] returns on one line and i need each sublist to return on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole function is messy, so I just rewrote it:

```
def display_game(guesses, clues):
    output = 'Guess\tClues\n****************\n'

    for i in range(len(guesses)):
        for letter in guesses[i]:
            output += letter + ' '

        for letter in clues[i]:
            output += letter + ' '

        output += '\n'

    print(output)

display_game([['Y', 'P', 'G', 'G'], ['O', 'O', 'G', 'G']], [['b', 'b'], ['b','b', 'b', 'b']])
```

You can try it out [here](https://repl.it/NPUf).